# Running awk command and print $1 with script that get arguments

Tags: bash, awk

I have my script (called test.sh) as follow:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in "cat myfile | awk -F',' '{print $1}'"; do
     .....
```

My problem is that my script receives arguments (`./tesh.sh arg1 arg2`) and `'{print $1}'` take the script argument (`arg1`) instead awk result, how can I solve it?

Comment: `for i in "$(cat myfile | awk -F',' '{print $1}')"; do`

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like an [XY Problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). What is it that you're trying to do here, anyway? What's in `myfile`, and what will you be doing within your `for` loop? There may be a better way to do it.

Comment: @ghoti I must admit, I've seen the XY link a lot of times, but this is the first time I read the page. Is there not a better page we can use to explain XY, this page is to my opinion a bit rude wrt beginners.

Comment: @kvantour, Greg's whole wiki, while it contains gold, can be a bit harsh. You should see him in IRC though! :-) This is the original, and I've always found it a fun read. http://xyproblem.info/ is a redacted version of the original. I find [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/174723) is a good bet when the question is about something other than bash. There's even a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) for it, though it's a bit short. Perlmonks [has one too](https://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341) with a lot of good comments; perhaps too many.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original problem is that you wrote the `$1` between double-quotes.

```
"cat myfile | awk -F',' '{print $1}'"
```

bash variables are still substituted by their value if they are in a double-quoted string, disregarding the fact that they are between single-quotes inside the double-quotes. This is the reason why `$1` is being replaced by `arg1`.

The second problem is that you want to execute the command:

```
cat myfile | awk -F',' '{print $1}'
```

but for this you need to use the notation `$( command )` or `` `command` ``, the latter is however not advised as nesting is difficult.

So, your for-loop should read something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for i in $(awk -F ',' '{print $1}' myfile); do
   ...
done
```